# If $f$ is uniformly continuous and $(z_n)_n$ a Cauchy sequence in $D\subset \mathbb{C}$, then $(f(z_n))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous and $(z_n)_n$ a Cauchy sequence in
>   $D\subset \mathbb{C}$, then $(f(z_n))_n$ is a Cauchy  sequence.

**My attempt:**

Let $f$ uniformly continuous in $D\subset \mathbb{C}, f: D\to \mathbb{C}$ and $(z_n)_n$ a Cauchy sequence in $D$. Let $(a_n)_n:=f((z_n)_n)$.

In order to show that $(a_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $D$ , for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ with $|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon$ für $m,n\geq N$. Since $(a_n)_n\subset D$ and $x,y\in D$, one can deduce by the definition of uniform continuity $ \overbrace{\left(|x-y|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon \text { mit } \varepsilon , \delta >0\right)}^{\text{Uniform continuity}}$ that with $x:=(a_n)_n$ and $y:=(a_m)_m$ the claim ist true,

Comment: You actually have no idea as to whether the $a_n$ are in $D$.

Comment: you're right, missed that. It is $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\varepsilon > 0$ find $\delta > 0$ that $\forall x, y \in D$ if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon $ $(1)$

For $\delta$ find $N$ that $\forall n, m\geq N$ we have $|z_n - z_m| < \delta$

Puting $x = z_n$ and $y = z_m$ we get the definition of Cauchy sequence for $f(z_n)$:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists N \; \forall n, m \geq N \; |f(z_n)-f(z_m)| < \varepsilon$

Comment: hence proved? I don't understand?!

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic, yes, actually. It's a definition of Cauchy sequence for $f(z_n)$

Comment: "Together we get ....". What happened to "$|x-y|<\delta $?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic better ?

Comment: :-) thanks :-).